# Origins of "joinable" and "unjoinable" in multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

Why does POSIX use the words "**joinable**" and "**unjoinable**" to describe between a thread that is/was/might/could-in-the-future-be doing something and a thread that is idle and waiting to be deleted? What was the initiative behind the selection of these particular words to describe the current state of a thread?

Comment: POSIX uses the same exact terminology.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: "It's the accepted terminology in existing threading implementations and API specifications" seems like a good answer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This doesn't answer my question.. Just because POSIX uses the same teminology doesn't really say anything about the origins of the two words. WHY have these words been selected to represent thread actions?

Comment: Surely your question should be why the thread `join()` function is called "join" (personally, I've never thought it was a good name).

Comment: It's just how the English language works.

Comment: lost in the past. Its a weak name for the operation to wait for a thread to finish. 'join me at the exit' kind of thing. Surely wait would be better, but that  verb aleady exists in posix

Comment: imho either "because POSIX uses same terminology" is the answer or the question is too broad. I mean to get the ultimate origin of the words you need to look into a dictionary :P

Comment: `and a thread that is idle and waiting to be deleted?` or detached.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree it's the accepted terminology. :-) I'm just curious as to why these were selected. They could have used any other term, which could actually be closer, meaning-wise, to the current state of a thread. I believe that the C++ committee chose the words "joinable" and "unjoinable" for a reason. It's the reason I'm looking for...

Comment: why C++ committe chose them is most likely because they were already commonly used since decades. Why posix chose them is a different question, no?

Comment: @UKMonkey I meant the "unjoinable" threads. The threads that have been constructed by a default ctor and have no function to run, have been moved from, have been joined or detached.

Comment: @NeilButterworth That too.. But I want to focus on these two terms first.

Comment: @tobi303 A dictionary wouldn't do me any good. I have several theories as to why the two words have been used, one of which was mentioned by pm100 in a comment above. But I am after the true reason. Also, it feels like Concurrent C++ has the worst selection of named terms compared to other C++ names. Why? Is it because concurrency was only very recently embedded in C++, starting from C++11?

Comment: the words made it into the C++ standard because they are commonly used since long time in posix already. What else do you want to hear? Why they are used in posix is a slightly different question, but it seems like you specifically ask for the C++ standard

Comment: @tobi303 Fair enough. I don't mind editing the question if that would make more sense.

Comment: POSIX itself merely standardized existing terminology that was already in use, in this context. As far as how the term "join" came about, it's probably lost in the mists of time, and this particular operation was always described as "joining two threads into one". Two threads come in. One comes out; and the logical opposite of "fork". That's the likely, ultimate origin of the term.

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe use this kind of mental model to explain the terminology:
[image]